# Adding "Sale" product category to products that are on sale in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-wordpress

As part of a WooCommerce site I want to have a sale page that lists sale items (with pagination and filtering). I think the best way to do this is to have a 'Sale' category that is added automatically to any posts that are part of the sale (as category pages allow for filtering and pagination automatically.

I have this code so far to programatically add the sale category to products when you save them:

```
function update_test( $product) { 
wp_set_object_terms($product, 'sale', 'product_cat', true );
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'update_test', 1, 2);`
```

However, I only want this to happen if a product is on sale (i.e has sale price set) so that saving posts that are not on sale does not add the sale category. I have tried several different things, but have had no luck. I tried this, but it didnt work:

```
function update_test( $product ) { 
if($product->is_on_sale()){
wp_set_object_terms($product, 'sale', 'product_cat', true );
}
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'update_test', 1, 2);`
```

but this just made my site freeze on save.

Any ideas?

Andy

Comment: There is a plugin that creates an On Sale page for all your sale products, which has pagination: https://wordpress.org/plugins/on-sale-page-for-woocommerce/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated 2** *(October 2018)*

**`save_post`** is a WordPress hook that works with **`$post_id`** argument and target all kind of posts. You need to target **`product`** custom WooCommerce `post_type` first in a condition (and **`publish`** `post_status`).

Also as it's not a post object you can't use **`is_on_sale()`** method with it. But you can use **`get_post_meta()`** function to check if the **sale price** is set in the product.

Here is the fully functional and tested code *(for **simple products only**)*:

```
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'update_product_set_sale_cat' );
function update_product_set_sale_cat( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_product', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    if( get_post_status( $post_id ) == 'publish' && isset($_POST['_sale_price']) ) {
        $sale_price = $_POST['_sale_price'];

        if( $sale_price >= 0 && ! has_term( 'Sale', 'product_cat', $post_id ) ){
            wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'sale', 'product_cat', true );
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Related: [Auto remove Sale product category from not on sale products in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575108/auto-remove-sale-product-category-from-not-on-sale-products-in-woocommerce/52581951#52581951)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

I have tried this code in my function file and on save it gives me the following error message:

 "Call to undefined method WP_Post::is_on_sale()"

I have tried a few things and got this error back, not sure how to solve it.

Andy

Comment: Thanks! This is working well for simple products. Will have to have a think about how to make it work for variable products now. Man, woocommerce don't like to make anything easy.

Comment: Do you mean Woo Commerce is changing so that it works for variations? Or that you have maybe found a way to make it work for variable products? Either way, thanks so much for the help so far! I have been banging my head against a wall all of yesterday trying to sort this.

Comment: @AndrewIanHalloway this hook **works only for simple products**, as variations are updated via ajax (so the hook is not going to be fired and doesn't detect anything)… **ALSO the product categories** can be set for the variable product but **NOT for a particular variation** of this variable product… Sorry about that :( … I will try to find something for that (on my little free time) but it's going to be much more difficult…

Comment: No problem! Thanks for the help up to here. I suspected that it would be impossibly hard for the variable products. Might have to keep with manually adding and removing the sale category for now. Will update this if I ever do find a solution for both though!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think a more convenient way of doing this, that **also works on variable products**, would be adding the following in child theme's function.php (or via a plugin, etc):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'update_product_set_sale_cat', 10, 2 );

function update_product_set_sale_cat( $product_id, $product ) {
    if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        wp_add_object_terms($product_id, "sale", 'product_cat');
    } else { // this will also remove the sale category when the product in no longer on sale
        wp_remove_object_terms($product_id, "sale", 'product_cat');
    }
}
```

It uses the [`woocommerce_update_product`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-data-stores-class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.html#source-view.275) hook which runs whenever a product is updated/created in the database.