# WooCommerce - Send notification email when updating order with "save_post" hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

WooCommerce creates a new post when new orders are created of **`shop_order`** post type. So I want to send notification email of the order using wordpress `save_post` action hook.

I wrote the below code :

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'notify_shop_owner_new_order', 10, 3 );
function notify_shop_owner_new_order( $post_ID, $post ) {
    if( $post->post_type == 'shop_order' ) {
        $headers = 'From: foo <foo@bar.com>';

        $to = 'foo@bar.com';
        $subject = sprintf( 'New Order Received' );
        $message = sprintf ('Hello, musa ! Your have received a new order from .Check it out here :');

        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
    }
}
```

But it does not work.

And if I use below without checking the post type it works:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'notify_shop_owner_new_order', 10, 3 );
function notify_shop_owner_new_order( $post_ID, $post ) {
    $headers = 'From: foo <foo@bar.com>';

    $to = 'foo@bar.com';
    $subject = sprintf( 'New Order Received' );
    $message = sprintf ('Hello, musa ! Your have received a new order from .Check it out here :');

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
```

I don't understand what is the problem. I need to use function parameters `$post` and `$post_id` to get the post link.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the default woocommerce order notifications?

Comment: some custom post types are being registered with "public" set to false.

Comment: please check `$post->post_status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated

It's better to use `woocommerce_new_order` dedicated hook:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'notify_shop_owner_new_order', 10, 2 );
function notify_shop_owner_new_order( $order_id, $order ){
    $headers = 'From: Someone <wordpress@someone.com>';

    $to = 'musa.ssmc42@gmail.com';
    $subject = __( 'New Order Received' );
    $message = __('Hello, Someone ! You have received a new order from … Check it out here.');

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
```

Code is tested and works…

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

If you want to make it work on order update too, add:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_order', 'notify_shop_owner_new_order', 10, 2 );
```

---

Similar answer: [Adding "Sale" product category to products that are on sale in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965522/adding-sale-category-to-products-that-are-on-sale-using-save-post-hook/40966012#40966012)